# Printing out std::array with strings not working

Tags: c++, arrays, string, cout

I have the following code and it is not printing out to console:

```
void generateRandomStringArray(array<string, N> &arrayRef)
{
    cout << "Generating random string array..." << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        arrayRef[i] = randomString();
        cout << "Value of i = " << i << ": " << stoi(arrayRef[i]) << endl;
        cout << arrayRef[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "Generating array successful." << endl;
};
```

The problem is at the line `cout << arrayRef[i] << endl;` and i get the error, that there is a unhandeld exception, but what is the problem? Why is the exception thrown and how can I correct this?

Exception trace:

```
First-chance exception at 0x76EFC42D in SortingAlgorithms.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::invalid_argument at memory location 0x0344F8EC.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

Comment: Please provide concrete error and exception messages.

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't with the call to `stoi`? Sometimes the debugger is off by a line. What is the callstack when the exception occurs?

Comment: `invalid_argument` suggests it might come from `stoi`. Does `randomString` produce something that's convertible to an integer?

Comment: That error means that the data you're sending to `stoi` is royally messed up.  Please check that the string is indeed a valid number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swap the lines:

```
    cout << "Value of i = " << i << ": " << stoi(arrayRef[i]) << endl;
    cout << arrayRef[i] << endl;
```

to

```
    cout << arrayRef[i] << endl;
    cout << "Value of i = " << i << ": " << stoi(arrayRef[i]) << endl;
```

and You'll see the error is at the `stoi` call, where you're calling `stoi` with some broken string.